# anchor does not work in collection view cell layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell, ios-autolayout

I want to add a collectionView to my CustomCollectionViewController's cell, with constant space in both leading and trailing position, I'v tried Anchor type and Virtual Format type, but it seems that anchor does not work as I want. the trailing space is missing.

here is my code:

```
class CategoryCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    let appView:UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let view = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        return view
    }()

    func setupViews() {
        contentView.addSubview(appView)
        let layoutGuide = contentView.layoutMarginsGuide

        appView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        appView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        appView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        appView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

//      addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-8-[v0]-8-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": appView]))
//      addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|[v0]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["v0": appView]))
    }

}
```

[layout with Anchor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZFvP.png)

but if you use the old virtual format style, it works fine, it makes me confused

[layout with virtual format string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIbWi.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constant value of trailingAnchor.constraint needs to be -8 instead of 8.

```
appView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
```